# syntax error else {, what does it mean?

Tags: jquery

I dont quite this syntax error I am having when it keeps saying else { in code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var courseinfo = <?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?> ;

    $('#coursesDrop').change(function () {
        var courseId = $(this).val();

        /*
            You only need to do all of this if user selects a course, so check that first.
        */
        if (courseId !== '') {
            /*
                Iterate over courses and, if the one we want exists, populate its info.
            */
            for (var i = 0, l = courseinfo.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) {
                    $('#currentDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                    $('#newDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                    $('#currentCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);
                    $('#newCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);

                    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                    var split = text.split(' - ');
                    $('#currentCourseNo').val(split[0]);
                    $('#currentCourseName').val(split[1]);

                    /*
                        Without this break, the loop will continue until i = l.
                        We've already found our match, no need to continue.
                    */
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $('#currentCourseNo,#currentCourseName,#currentDuration,#currentCourseId').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Brackets seems correct but why am I getting this syntax error for the code above?

The exact error says `Syntaxerror: syntax error` and then in the view page source it just higlights this `else{`.

`var courseinfo = <?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?> ;` outputs this below in page source:

```
var courseinfo = [{"CourseId":1,"CourseNo":"INFO101","CourseName":"Bsc Information Communication Technology","Duration":"4"},{"CourseId":2,"CourseNo":"INFO102","CourseName":"Bsc Computing","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":8,"CourseNo":"INFO103","CourseName":"Business and Finance","Duration":"3"},{"CourseId":9,"CourseNo":"INFO107","CourseName":"Mathematics","Duration":"4"}];
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Where is the error ? And how is the generated code ?

Comment: Also, you should try to mimize the example by removing blocks of code until the syntax error disappears. This helps in finding where the error is.

Comment: I ran the code through jshint and didn't get any errors. Are you sure the error is in this block of code?

Comment: `var courseinfo = <? php echo json_encode($courseInfo); ?> ;` are you using `PHP` in javascript ?

Comment: Your braces are matched correctly. What does <? php echo json_encode($courseInfo); ?> produce?

Comment: @geedubb this shouldn't invalidate the javascript syntax... unless it actually gets to the browser.

Comment: @JanDvorak OP tags show javascript, so I assume the script is quite a bit invalid after that line

Comment: The question doesn't remotely match the accepted answer. I suggest closing and deleting this, it's clearly either not a real question, or too localized. It's certainly not going to be of any use to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't sure the problems are located ...
Because you don;t show any html line ...
But would you like to try this code:

```
$(function(){
var courseinfo = <?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?>;
$('#coursesDrop').change(function(){
    var courseId = $(this).val();

    /*
        You only need to do all of this if user selects a course, so check that first.
    */
    if (courseId != ''){
        /*
            Iterate over courses and, if the one we want exists, populate its info.
        */
        for (i = 0;i < courseinfo.length;i++){
            if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId){
                $('#currentDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                $('#newDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                $('#currentCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);
                $('#newCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);

                var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                var split = text.split(' - ');
                $('#currentCourseNo').val(split[0]);
                $('#currentCourseName').val(split[1]);

                /*
                    Without this break, the loop will continue until i = l.
                    We've already found our match, no need to continue.
                */
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#currentCourseNo,#currentCourseName,#currentDuration,#currentCourseId').val('');
    }
    });
});
```

If it won't work, i say sorry okay ....
Good luck

Comment: What are the changes compared to OP's original code?

Comment: I fix <?php tag ... if() statement too...

Comment: `courseId != ''` is different from `courseId !== ''`. Both are valid syntax. this doen't count as a fix (unless you explain why the latter is wrong).

Comment: Yes it was the extra if statement that was causing the problem as I had 2 similar if statements, thanks

Comment: @user1861818 what do you mean? `!==` vs. `!=` couldn't cause a syntax error.

Comment: oh sir, i know it doesn't count as fix...
But it will easing in read than the first code ...

Comment: It wasn't the sapce in the php tag as there is no space haha

Comment: @MichaelAntonius but `!==` means something different than `!=`. Exchanging them is likely to introduce bugs (`0 !== ""` is true, `0 != ""` is false).

Comment: i think `===` and `!==` usually for ask the boolean value ...
Not for string (In my opinion)

Comment: @MichaelAntonius: *"i think === and !== usually for ask the boolean value ... Not for string (In my opinion)"* It isn't a matter of opinion, and [`===` is perfectly valid for comparing strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4).

Answer (score 3):

You should open the page in the browser, get the error, and do View Source to see what actually went to the browser.

The likely culprit is this line:

```
var courseinfo = <?php echo json_encode($courseInfo); ?> ;
```

Three possibilities:

1. <s>I'm not a PHP expert, is `<? php` (with the space after `?`) really a valid opening tag (as opposed to `<?php` **without** the space)? Because if it isn't, it could be that PHP isn't processing it, and so that text is getting sent to the browser verbatim. Which naturally would be a problem.</s> You claim the space isn't really there.
2. <s>If that isn't it, I suspect that `$courseInfo` in PHP isn't what you expect it to be, and so isn't getting output correctly.</s> You've now quoted what gets output, which is a valid array literal.
3. <s>If the text you quoted isn't in a file that PHP will pre-process, that would be a problem, as the code will get sent to the browser. Normally, web servers are configured to use PHP to pre-process `.php` files, but not `.js` files. So if the text you've quoted is in a `.js` file, it will go to the browser as-is (with the PHP code in it), which probably isn't want you want.</s> I'm guessing that as you've quoted the output as having been processed, it must be getting pre-processed.
4. My final thought is that you have an invisible character in your text near the `else` in question. Try deleting that entire line (probably the couple of lines on either side, just in case) and retyping them (carefully).

Comment: json_encode always produces a valid javascript literal - if it does get evaluated by PHP, of course.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yeah, not being a PHP expert, I wasn't 100% sure what it did with edge cases (e.g., whatever the PHP equivalent of `undefined` is, as JSON doesn't have `undefined`).

Comment: There is no space on this line of code, it is just when I pasted the code that it displays the spaces

Comment: I don't think `<? php` is a valid opening tag. I think it's a short tag followed by a syntax error (missing semicolon after `php` + a bunch of warnings)

Comment: @user1861818: That makes no sense, why would pasting text magically add a space after `<?`? The advice stands, though: Look at what actually got sent to the browser.

Comment: @user1861818: Just for clarity, I've added a pointer to the space in question. I suspect if you look at your code, you'll find that it's there.

Comment: @user1861818: Add I've added a third possible explanation.

Comment: There is no space, it is just when I pasted the line to SO that it made a space, but trust me there is no space. If you write that line of code in a text editor and then paste it on SO, you will see that it creates a space

Comment: @user1861818 it doesn't. Perhaps you have a zero-width space in your code (that is causing the syntax error)?

Answer (score 3):

If indeed the line shown in the comment and by T.J. Crowder is in your javascript, kindly go back to your `php` script and remove the space from `<? php`

Comment: There is no space, it is just when I pasted the line to SO that it made a space, but trust me there is no space. If you write that line of code in a text editor and then paste it on SO, you will see that it creates a space

Comment: @user1861818 I have not encountered a _single_ case of SO altering the copy/pasted string (except normal markdown formatting. Perhaps you have a zero-width space in your code?)

Comment: @user1861818 I just tried copying the code from notepad++ into a new question, and surprisingly SO does not add any spaces. Anyway even when the space is not there: Are you using `ASP.NET`? Do you really have `PHP` correctly installed? is the file extension on your server set to an extension that will be parsed by `PHP`? You must provide more info.

Comment: @barts info already provided. The PHP is evaluated as desired.